# How to handle argument logic with argparse module in Python

Tags: python, terminal, arguments, argparse

I'm writing a script which I want to be able to run in two modes:

1. --testall - no additional arguments needed
2. --test - arguments: -f, -t, -sm necessary

but I don't know how to code that logic using argparse module. Ideas? 
When I run

> python3 test_argparse.py --testall

it throws:

```
usage: test_argparse.py [-h] [--testall TESTALL | --test TEST] [-f FROM]
                        [-t TO] [-sm {preserve,noresdir}]
test_argparse.py: error: argument --testall: expected one argument
```

So far...

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Tests fast copy operation. Checks MD5 hashes, file and directory "
                                             "permissions, sync modes (sync, keep, recopy, resync, preserve, resdir, "
                                             "noresdir) and outputs the result to MySQL database on Nemo")
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("--testall", help="tests copy operations between all available zones", type=str)
group.add_argument("--test", help="tests copy operation between specific zones", type=str)

parser.add_argument("-f", "--from", help="name of the zone to copy from")
parser.add_argument("-t", "--to", help="name of the zone to copy to")
parser.add_argument("-sm", "--syncmode", help="mode to use when copying", choices=['preserve', 'noresdir'])
args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(vars(args))
    if args.testall:
        print('Testing TESTALL mode')
    elif args.test:
        print('Testing TEST mode')
    else:
        print('Testing everything else')
```

Comment: For a start, make `testall` and `test` 'store_true'.  That way they won't require arguments.   Or make `test` a `nargs=3` and omit the the others.  You may still need to implement some sort of post-parsing tests.  `argparse` only provides the mutually_exclusive `xor` test, and subparsers.

Comment: Providing logical default values can also eliminate the need for fancy testing.  Keep in mind that you want the API to be clear and easy for your users.  It's hard to explain complicated conditions, especially in a concise `usage` line.

Comment: I added `group.add_argument("--test", help="tests copy operation between specific zones", action='store_true')` and at the end also `uargs = vars(args)
    print(uargs)

    if uargs['testall'] is True:
        print('Testing TESTALL mode')
    elif uargs['test']:
        if None in [uargs['from'], uargs['to'], uargs['syncmode']]:
            parser.error('When using --test you have to specify --from, --to and --syncmode arguments!')
            sys.exit(1)
        print('Testing TEST mode')
    else:
        print('Testing everything else')`